# Add sentinel layer to leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, wms, sentinel

This is how i define my url for get wms image for sentinel:
Sentinel2:

> `"https://kade.si/cgi-bin/mapserv?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Landsat-8&TILED=true&format=image%2Fvnd.jpeg-png&WIDTH=320&HEIGHT=320&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&MAP_RESOLUTION=112.5&BBOX={x}{y}{x}{y}"`,

I have problems with define how to get **&BBOX={x}{y}{x}{y}**

In this image i see that the request is successfull

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But when i copu the request URL I see this message:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException>
msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Wrong number of arguments for BBOX.
</ServiceException>
```

How to set the right Bbox parameteres..

i read that bbox

Bounding box for map extent. Value is minx,miny,maxx,maxy in units of the SRS.

Also this is working request url:

```
https://kade.si/cgi-bin/mapserv?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/jpeg&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Landsat-8&TILED=true&format=image%2Fvnd.jpeg-png&WIDTH=320&HEIGHT=320&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&MAP_RESOLUTION=112.5&BBOX=2861802.338996999%2C5390950.730896911%2C2866694.30880725%2C5395842.700707162
```

Why bbox parameters are so long numbers:**BBOX=2861802.338996999%2C5390950.730896911%2C2866694.30880725%2C5395842.700707162**

Can you help me what to add in the bbox parameter so leaflet to get the right parameters and to view the layer...

Comment: Have you read through the [Leaflet WMS tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html)?

Comment: yes but i have the same error this bbox parameter...

Comment: In that tutorial, what does it say about the `bbox` parameter?

Comment: can you give me advice how should the link to be to see the map with sentinel overlay....BIG thank you if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Javascript

```
// Declare map using EPSG3857 projection (default is also 3857, so just optionnal here) and set center
const center = [38, 20.472157];
const map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
}).setView(center, 4);

// Define wmsOptions for wmsLayer
const wmsOptions = {
    layers: 'Landsat-8',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png'
}

// WMS Layer constructor
const wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://kade.si/cgi-bin/mapserv', wmsOptions);

// add To the map
wmsLayer.addTo(map);
```

Don't forget to set a height to the div map :

Style CSS :

```
<style>
    #map {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML Element :

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

See example with your WMS here: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bfrndvmh/5/)

Comment: how can i add this like option in dropdown menu, so when yhe user select Landsat the mapo changes

Comment: This is a whole another question, not relative to the former one. Please start a new post if solution worked for the specific use case. Thanks mate